# Can I get Facebook Id of any user through Profile URL or Username?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get user if of any facebook user using its profile url or its username.

I want to implement the same functionality as shown in [this website](https://findmyfbid.com/).

I have tried using `https://graph.facebook.com/username` but it gives me the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (username)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "G8AjtLUd3AC"
   }
}
```

I have also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418740/get-facebook-id-from-url-of-any-profile-account) and it says that facebook does not allow getting an id from the username.If it's true then how does [this website](https://findmyfbid.com/) gets the id

Comment: _“then how does this website gets the id”_ - by scraping, which is not allowed. _“I want to implement the same functionality as [...]”_ - what for? It doesn’t even serve any real purpose, you can not do much with a user’s global id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Facebook ID from URL of any profile account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418740/get-facebook-id-from-url-of-any-profile-account)

Answer (score 1):

you try old method ...for new you need facebook access token

and try like this type-

```
$access_token = "EAAAAAYsX7TsBAH1efzbZAhqJREQfwzZCNIZBgGVbpxoLaoZBOVx4KminpzqkiczMC19pVdjqX6fVj3jIxxdGaROSyr04ZCYmhSe59UMZAwZAKH5YJ7dnawHwgYSLvbJa4TV8kqAkO6l5mcgVIVfeE6trgm7hh01RJ7SB0hDc7scQ8YineE0exabZCmuYOvnldngEopPEYBZAZBVCZC4knDHGNZCKwk0fj36526MZD";


function getFacebookIdFromUrlandUsername($url,$access_token) {
/**
 * Taken from https://www.allautoliker.com/find_id, the valid formats are:
 * dr.p.pareek
 * https://www.facebook.com/leloweb
 * https://m.facebook.com/dr.p.pareek
 * https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001148755604
 */
$correctURLPattern = '/^https?:\/\/(?:www|m)\.facebook.com\/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$/';
if (!preg_match($correctURLPattern, $url, $matches)) {
    $getinf = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' .$url.'/?access_token='.$access_token;
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents($getinf), true);
    return $info;
}else{
    $getinf = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' .$matches[1].'/?access_token='.$access_token;
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents($getinf), true);
    return $info;
}
}
$find_id = "dr.p.pareek";
$user = getFacebookIdFromUrlandUsername($find_id,$access_token);
 //echo '<pre>';
//print_r($user);

echo $user['id'];
```