# flutter firebase_auth OAuth exception: errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)}

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter and attempting to add firebase_auth GoogleSignIn to my app.  I've followed the instructions of about 5 samples I've found online but keep getting the error when I run the app:

```
E/GraphResponse( 8321): {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (CHANGE-ME)}
```

I've posted the code for my app here for review:  git@github.com:naustin/servicereport_autherror.git

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886468/facebook-cannot-query-users-by-their-username-solution, https://github.com/criso/fbgraph/issues/98, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643821/can-i-get-facebook-id-of-any-user-through-profile-url-or-username

Answer (score 0):

Based from the error thrown, username can't be used in the query. I've checked the code snippets from the GitHub repository that you've shared and it looks like you're using `requestMask` on your query.

```dart
final http.Response response = await http.get(
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
      '?requestMask.includeField=person.names',
  headers: await _currentUser.authHeaders,
);
```

Checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#query-parameters), `requestMask` has been deprecated. It's recommended to use `personFields` instead.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem. The problem is the URL: `'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
      '?requestMask.includeField=person.names'` should be `"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=${person.names}"`

Comment: @ChrisPi this is a query that returns people.connections.list - `person.names` is the field restriction.

Comment: So? Is the request  legit?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Code from user @Omatt the problem is, that the server gets the wrong field to search. Dots are not allowed, therefore the server just gets `person` in the requestMask:

```
'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=person.names'
```

Should be written with *String Interpolation*:

```dart
"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=${person.names}"
```